# First Contentful Paint measured with almost 6 s although content is visible in second screen

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I did everything I could to optimize my Wordpress site and got rid of most of the recommendations by PageSpeed Insights. I use WP Rocket caching plugin, Optimole image optimization and Cloudflare CDN.

Google PageSpeed Insights got somewhat better but still, especially on mobile, results are far from good - although all of the recommendations that were there in the beginning and that I could get rid of (without custom coding and without breaking the site) are now gone.

There is one thing that strikes me as odd about the PageSpeed Insights results. That is that First Contentful Paint is measured with something between 5 and 6 seconds although the screenshots of the page that Google presents clearly show that there is contentful paint in the second frame already. See image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SkSe.jpg).

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

The only remaining points on your suggestions are 1. Remove Unused css, and 2.Defer non critical resources( I think, cus the text is in German)

Point 2 affects time to first paint the most.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshots you see in PSI are not in real time.

Also there is a slight (bug?) discrepancy between screenshots and actual performance as PSI uses a simulated slow-down of the page rather than an applied slowdown (so it loads the page at full speed then adjusts the figures to account for bandwidth and Round Trip Time to the server caused by higher latency).

If you run a Lighthouse audit (Google Chrome -> F12 -> audits 0> run audits) with the  throttling set to 'applied' rather than 'simulated' you will see it is about 5 seconds before a meaningful paint.

Lighthouse is the engine that powers Page Speed Insights now so the same information should be in both.

With regards to your site speed you have a load of blank SVGs being loaded for some reason and your CSS and JS files need combining (do it manually, plugins don't tend to do a good job here) to reduce the number of requests your site makes. (It can only make 8 requests at a time and on 4G the round-trip / latency to your server means these add up quickly e.g. 40 files = 5 * 8 round trips at 100ms latency = 500ms of dead time waiting for a response)